# regular expression for string with dot del

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regular expression for the following string:

> SQL Err 100 on \TEST1.$PROD01.TEST.XYZ562

I want to search for anything with `TEST*.$PROD*.TEST.XYZ*.`

Can anyone help with the regular expression?

Comment: Something like `TEST\d*\.\$PROD\d*\.TEST\.XYZ.*` might work.  https://regex101.com/r/lD6yQ5/1

Answer (score 0):

Basic effort was required, you could just tried it yourself and, I believe, find an answer on your own! For future needs, try site [regex101.com](https://regex101.com), it helps to work with regulars.

So, you need to find a string containing `TEST`, then something, then `.` then $PROD value, again anything, and `.TEST.XYZ`, and finally anything, where `$PROD` is, as I understand, a variable without special characters (as `[](){}.^\`).

So, you get that:

```
TEST[^.]*\.<$PROD value should go here>[^.]*\.TEST\.XYZ
```

That should be enough. You will need to supstitude variable `$PROD` on your own, but I don't know your language, so I can't help with that part. Maybe something like this:

```
"TEST[^.]*\." + $PROD + "[^.]*\.TEST\.XYZ"
```